# Last modification and size of a web page

Tags: java

I would like to ask how to get the last modification date and the size(eg, 500KB) of a webpage?
For the modification date: I have tried lots of webpage, but all of them return 0.
e.g.

```
URL url = new URL(htmlList.elementAt(i));
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
time = connection.getLastModified();
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java, but I'm guessing you will need to request the HEAD after connect in order for the size and modification date to become available.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `Content-Length` header or the size. `connection.getContentLength()`

The `Last-Modified` header may not be set for dynamic pages, but anyway try it (Stackoverflow sets it, for example). If it is 0, assume the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:-

```
// Demonstrate URLConnection. 
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;

class UCDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int c;
        URL hp = new URL("http", "www.google.com", 80, "/");
        System.out.print(hp);
        URLConnection hpCon = hp.openConnection();
        System.out.println("Date: " + new Date(hpCon.getDate()));
        System.out.println("Content-Type: " +
        hpCon.getContentType());
        System.out.println("Expires: " + hpCon.getExpiration());
        System.out.println("Last-Modified: " +
        new Date(hpCon.getLastModified()));
        int len = hpCon.getContentLength();
        System.out.println("Content-Length: " + len);
        if (len > 0)
        {
            System.out.println("=== Content ===");
            InputStream input = hpCon.getInputStream();
            int i = len;
            while (((c = input.read()) != -1) && (-i > 0))
            {
                System.out.print((char)c);
            }
            input.close();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No Content Available");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated web pages generally do not have a Last-Modified field, and different web pages include dates in different ways. Some sites do not even include such a date, including "© " at the bottom. You could try looking for a date near the bottom or the top, but reliably extracting the date from the web page would have to be site-specific.